# wget forbidden but can download with firefox

Tags: wget, firefox, download

I'm used to download addons from https://www.curseforge.com with my own script, but now, it's not working anymore.
Each try I do, I get :

```
$ LANG=C wget https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/classiccastbars/download
--2019-09-23 19:54:13--  https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/classiccastbars/download
Resolving www.curseforge.com... 104.19.146.132, 104.19.147.132
Connecting to www.curseforge.com|104.19.146.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-09-23 19:54:13 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I tried with User-agent etc... without success.

EDIT :
As suggested by @alessiosavi, in chrome, with "copy as curl", here is what I get (I can see 2 get requests):

1)

```
curl 'https://geoservice.curse.com/geo/get' -X OPTIONS -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Origin: https://www.curseforge.com' -H 'Referer: https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/classiccastbars' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' --compressed
```

2)

```
curl 'https://geoservice.curse.com/geo/get' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Referer: https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/classiccastbars' -H 'Origin: https://www.curseforge.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-type: application/json' --compressed
```

Or may be this one :

```
curl 'https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/classiccastbars/' -H 'authority: www.curseforge.com' -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' -H 'cookie: __cfduid=d6db4b9c10ef925c90eb1e08149a96a201569420606; Unique_ID_v2=389cbe9684ea464b9e6616e7cbe84b57; ResponsiveSwitch.DesktopMode=1; _ga=GA1.2.1639390131.1569420607; __utmz=94490894.1569420608.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _gid=GA1.2.465525518.1569862527; cdmgeo=mq; __cf_bm=b234703f5bd6f21761c0002828ff592ccea25d53-1569873659-1800-AeS9BMnquwJXGm3hqxR7oFz8yIgB6GrqsaNUQWNeTm/dwySd97EpXaWe8fs/PM84TblHp5/hGprjBm6gPR9cPVs=; __utma=94490894.1639390131.1569420607.1569862527.1569873663.3; __utmc=94490894; __utmt=1; __utmt_b=1; __utmb=94490894.2.10.1569873663; AWSALB=HqlxzmKRURpTjWDSKP5YL4yg+YY+qh/dSgTQJ82Za+TjPHmufaPMLuwicjEayRNj6PEAv3oX/qXgqRO1VfopMN9crXu20eUJ+CHykVh2xXodkqFLI6A7U7lizGeP' --compressed
```

Comment: Most probably new applicational glue as the answer says + security site protections and/or Javascript on top after you get the User Agent right. But I fail to see how debugging and getting past  site protections is on topic on a Unix forum about Unix questions.

Comment: I don't see any cookie in your request

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021799/alternatives-for-wget-giving-error-403-forbidden

Answer (score 7):

Open your developer tab trough the F11 key, then go in the `network` tab. If you make the http call with the developer tab opened, you will see (usually under XHR http call) your request. You can now press `right click` over the request and `copy as cURL`.

#### ***NOTE:***

Be sure to hit ***copy as cURL*** instead of ***copy all as cURL***.

Now you can paste the request into a text editor and verify the cookie sent by the browser for authenticate the request.
Try to include (at least) all the ***cookies*** listed in the request.

Comment: And to explain the "403 Forbidden": The request in the browser likely includes authorization headers or cookies, and if you don't have those in your wget/curl call, the site will refuse the download.

Comment: @dirkt I understood that.

Comment: Ok.
I get a long line (that I can't paste here), and I don't really find how to use it in my wget command :(

Comment: Be sure to hit `copy as cURL` instead of `copy all as cURL`. Than paste the data into a text editor and you can view the plain headers

Comment: edited with result